# Correct usage of HTML5 <hr> tag

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm writing a new webpage for a company and I have (a sane subset of) HTML5/W3C recommendations in mind.

After reading the semantic meaning of `<hr />`, I was wondering if this was a good place to use it:

```
<section name="historyItem">
    <h2>2002</h2>
    <p>Dolorem ipsum dolor sit amet in 2002, consectetur [...]</p>
    <hr />
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

My line of reasoning is that, yes, that `<hr />` represents a thematic change from *section description* to *section links*, but I'm unsure about that.

Maybe "thematic change" means to have a new paragraph later on another subject, and thus my example wouldn't be "correct". What do you think?

(ps.: Yes, that `<ul>` is CSS-styled to fit a single line and look cool)

Answer (score 5):

I see what you mean. But personally I just wouldn't bother. Ask yourself why you're using the tag in the first place. If you want to delineate a change between the paragraph and the links, then in terms of pure mark-up I don't reckon it's required. If it's about the look and feel of your page (i.e. you want a rule demarcating the two areas), then again I'd question its usefulness, given that you can apply a border to either the paragraph or unordered list tags.

Of course, given that this is html5, you could go the whole hog and use the `<section>` tag…

Comment: They say there is an equivalence between `<hr />` and `</section><section>`, and since I'm already within a section, `<hr />` seems to be a better option.

And if somebody were to tell me that my example isn't semantically "correct", then I'd go styling the bottom/top borders of either element, indeed, since graphically that line is important.

Comment: Yep, and apologies for ignoring your use of `<section>` already; I wasn't paying proper attention!

Comment: No prob! Considering you were the only one to answer me, I appreciate it XD

Answer (score 2):

Thematically speaking, `<hr>` means the end of one "section" and the start of "another".  Essentially these should be appearing after your `<section>` tags, not within. Although semantically speaking, it doesn't really matter where you want to use them.

If your list of link items are relevant to the items ABOVE the `<hr>` tag (meaning relevant to your other elements within the `<section>` tag, then I do not recommend using `<hr>` there.  Instead, use CSS to differentiate border and underlines.

If you'd like additional reference, I've located this for you:
http://html5doctor.com/small-hr-element/

Comment: I think `hr` between sectioning content element doesn’t make sense, as there is a "break" *by definition*. See also the [example in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element): "There is no need for an `hr` element between the sections themselves, since the `section` elements and the `h1` elements imply thematic changes themselves."

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr): "The <hr> HTML element represents a thematic break between paragraph-level elements: for example, a change of scene in a story, or a shift of topic within a section." And is therefore used inside the same section. If you have two sections and need a visual separator, then a `<div>` with a custom class is actually more suited.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr): "The `<hr>` HTML element represents a thematic break between paragraph-level elements: for example, a change of scene in a story, or a shift of topic within a section." And is therefore used inside the same section. If you have two sections and need a visual separator, then a `<div>` with a custom class is actually more suited.